# Extract data frame variable

Tags: r, split, extract

I have a list of proteins in a column but they all end with _l
how do I remove _l from proteins ?
example:

nr2_l ,
nr1_l ,
pkca_l ,
p_lr1_l ,
p_ln_l

separate(protein_exp, c("protein", "l"), "_l")

but this then separates protein **p_lr1_l **
to :

| protein | l |
| --- | --- |
| p | r1 |

I want it to be :
| protein |      l    |
| --------| --------  |
| p_lr1   |     _l    |

Thanks

Comment: String Remove can do this. `stringr::str_remove("test_l", pattern="_l$")` the extra `$` dollar sign means "only match _l at the end of the string".

Comment: Or `sub("_l$", "", x)`: `x` is you column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String Remove from `stringr` library can do this.

```
library(tidyverse)
str_remove("test_l", pattern="_l$")
#or
str_remove(protein_exp, pattern="_l$")
```

The extra `$` dollar sign means "only match _l at the end of the string".

If your data is in a dataframe called df, you can use `mutate()`

```
df %>% mutate(protein = str_remove(protein_exp, pattern="_l$"))
```